# python regular expression find and replace html tag with specific attribute value

Tags: python, regex

Am trying to write a regular expression in python that would find all img tags where src attribute equal to a specific value.. I tried to write the below

```
   # where thm equal /public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82
   p = re.compile(r'<img.*?%s.*?>' % thm)
   print p.pattern
   print p.sub(linked_image, c)
```

and below what I got as an output

```
<img.*?/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82.*?>

<p><img src="/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82" alt=""></p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf </p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf 
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
```

Comment: what about using BeautifulSoup for this job? http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: I could use the beautifulSoup, but am altering content that is unstructured and it should maintain its structure without change. problem with beautifulSoup, I won't be able to output the processed soup to the previous structure as output... that's why i need to change replace string method

Comment: Please take a look at the new version - I found the error in the raw `thm` variable and proposed two solutions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution with LXML**

To compare a solution with Regular expressions and LXML I created another post:

An easier and more stable solution is to use `lxml` with `etree`. In that solution you
access certain DOM elements and edit them.

Convert the HTML string and get it through the right `xpath` e.g. `.//img`. The `xpath`
returns a list of all found elements where you can `get` and `set` the `src` attribute.
The function `etree.tostring(tree)` returns an edited string:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML('''<html>
                     <body>
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <img src="/media/old/another_logo.png" alt="" />
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        <p><img src="/media/old/logo.png" alt=""/></p>
                     </body>
                  </html>''')

imgs = tree.xpath('.//img')

for img in imgs:
    print 'OLD_SOURCE', img.get('src')
    img.set('src', '/media/new/python.jpg')

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output

```
OLD_SOURCE /media/old/another_logo.png
OLD_SOURCE /media/old/logo.png

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="/media/new/python.jpg" alt=""/>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><img src="/media/new/python.jpg" alt=""/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A solution with Regular Expressions**:

I realized that the string which was inserted into `thm` was not escaped.
So before adding it to your regular expression you need to escape all symbols with
an additional signification in the Regular Expression language - here, `?` and `.`.

I replaced `?` with `[?]{1}` and `.` with `\.`. The resulting regular expressions matches now the test string.

```
import re
thm = '/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82'

all_html_code = '''<img.*?/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82.*?>

<p><img src="/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82" alt=""></p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf </p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf
</p><p>lksj lksdfj lsdkfj sldkfj sldkfj lskdfj lsjf lksjf lksj flksdjf klsj flk dkj sdlkfj sdlkfj sldkjf sldkfj lsdkjf lskjflsjfsl lksdjf '''

escaped_thm = thm.replace('.', '\.').replace('?','[?]{1}')
p = re.compile(r'<img.*?src="(%s)".*?>' % escaped_thm)

test_img = '''<img src="/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82" alt="">'''
print p.match(test_img)

new_img_tag = '<img src="/python/logo.jpg" alt=""/>'
print p.sub(new_img_tag, all_html_code)
```

By the way, why are you looking for `<img src=""...>`? You could replace the `src` attribute directly:

```
escaped_thm = thm.replace('.', '\.').replace('?','[?]{1}')
p = re.compile(r'src="(%s)"' % escaped_thm)

replacement = '''src="/python/logo.jpg"'''
print p.sub(replacement, all_html_code)
```

**Output 1**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x... >
<img.*?/public_media/cache/84/b5/84b59e293cbdb7041b68a84977d62cf3.jpg?image_pk=82.*?>

<p><img src="/python/logo.jpg" alt=""/></p><p>lksj lksdfj ... lksdjf
```

**Output 2**

```
<p><img src="/python/logo.jpg" alt=""></p><p>lksj lksdfj ... lksdjf
```

After asking about a proper way to escape symbols of regular expressions ([Regular expression to escape regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609128/regular-expression-to-escape-regular-expressions)) - I can recommend an `re.escape` instead of the two `replace` methods.

**Using LXML**

Do you need to use regular expressions?
Regular expressions for HTML can be highly problematic. See more information and wonderful post here([RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).

I would rather use XPath like here.

Comment: I could use the beautifulSoup, but am altering content that is unstructured and it should maintain its structure without change. problem with beautifulSoup, I won't be able to output the processed soup to the previous structure as output... that's why i need to change replace string method

Comment: I added a solution with regex. Please check out the example above.