# Regular expression to escape regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Yesterday, I needed to add a file path to a regular expression creating a pattern like this:

```
"some_pattern/%s/more_pattern" % some_path
```

In the beginning the regular expression did not match, because `some_path` contained 
several regex specific symbols like `?` or `.`. As a quick fix I replaced them with `[?]{1}` and `.` with `\.`.

However, I asked myself if there isn't a more reliable or better way to clean a string from regex specific symbols.

- **Is such functionality supported in the Python Standard library?**
- **If not, do you know a regular expression to identify all regex symbols and clean them through a substitute?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just apply [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) and you'll be fine.

> `re.escape(string)`
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics
>   backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal
>   string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.